# Closed form for an infinite sum

Tags: summation

Let $\psi_q(z)$ be the q-DiGamma function defined for a real variable $\Re(z)>0$ as $$\psi_q(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma_q(z)}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (\Gamma_q(z))$$
where $\Gamma_q(z)$ is the q-Gamma function defined as $$\Gamma_q(z)=(1-q)^{1-z}\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q^{n+z}}$$

**Question** I am looking for a closed form (to the extent possible) for $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \psi_{e^{-2\pi}}(n+1)\left(\frac{1}{n^3}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was answering this on Mathematica Stack Exchange I will finish posting my effort

```
gamma[z_] := Evaluate[(1 - q)^(1 - z)*
   Product[(1 - q^(n + 1))/(1 - q^(n + z)), {n, 0, Infinity}]]

psi[z_] := Evaluate[D[1/(gamma[z]), z]*gamma[z]]

q = E^(-2 Pi);

Sum[psi[n + 1]*(1/n^3 - 1/(n + 1)^3), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

[image]

Looking at the `psi[n + 1]` term

```
psiSimplified = Simplify[psi[n + 1]]
```

> -QPolyGamma[0, -(Log[E^(-2 (1 + n) Pi)]/(2 Pi)), E^(-2 Pi)]

I'm not sure how Fred Hutch gets to the next step:

```
sum = Sum[QPolyGamma[n + 1, E^(-2*Pi)]*(1/n^3 - 1/(n + 1)^3), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

but it doesn't result in a closed form.

```
N[sum]
```

> 0.00184998

Comment: The answer is wrong. The psi (n+1) in the last sum must read psi[n+1].

Comment: Thanks @FredHucht

Comment: Still wrong. The sum does converge.

Comment: @FredHucht I guess I'm stumped.

Comment: Look at the OP's question. There is a sum over $n$, and all terms are in the sum: NSum[QPolyGamma[n + 1, E^(-2*Pi)]*(1/n^3 - 1/(n + 1)^3), {n, 1, Infinity}] -> 0.001849976368

Comment: The [`q-gamma function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QGamma.html) is a built-in symbol in Mathematica. The [`q-digamma function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QPolyGamma.html) is also a built-in symbol in Mathematica.